# Modify the number of rows in the legend of a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´m generating a plot using ggnet and would like to modify the legend so i can increase the number of rows in the legend.

So far this is what i´m trying but i get a fixed number of rows in the legend. How can i increase that number

```
p <-  ggnet2(net,
                  color = "Order",
                  palette = y,
                  alpha = 0.75,
                  size = 6, 
                  edge.label = "weight", 
                  edge.size=1,
                  edge.color="color",
                  edge.alpha = 0.5,
                  label = TRUE, 
                  label.size = 4)
```

I have tried this without success:

```
 p <- p + guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=40,byrow=TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend to reduce the number of colors by making subgroups. No one will read or understand such a busy legend.

Comment: Agree with you , still don´t know how to change the number of rows in the legend